# Why does log n! = ψ(n) + ψ(n/2) + ψ(n/3) + ψ(n/4) + ...?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I saw this formula - $\log n! = \sum_{k=1}^n\psi(\frac{n}{k})$ (where $\psi$ is the second Chebyshev function) - in a published paper (not a letter) of Ramanujan's with no citation.  To make it into a journal without citation, it must be fairly well-known, but I can't find a proof anywhere (the only other reference I can find at all is [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MangoldtFunction.html), where it's presented without proof, and the citation is a dead-tree book of which Amazon is out).  I feel like it's probably pretty easy, but try as I might, I can't come up with it on my own.

Comment: Hint: $\log n=\sum_{d\mid n}\Lambda(n)$. Changing the order of summation will be of use.

Comment: I thought of that, but I'm not really sure how to get from A to B.

Comment: I think the first proof is in Chebyshev's [_Mémoire sur les nombres premiers_](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1852_1_17_A19_0.pdf). He proved it by counting how often $\log p$ occured on either side.

Comment: The [Edwards book](https://www.amazon.com/Riemanns-Zeta-Function-Harold-Edwards/dp/0486417409/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1528319056&sr=8-1&keywords=edwards+riemann) is in stock at amazon.com, but you can also get it from Dover. However, pp. 50-54 with the derivation are available from the "Look Inside" feature, so you don't have to buy it just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer. I presume you are aware of the identity $\log k=\sum_{d\mid k}\Lambda(d)$. Summing this for $k$ from $1$ to $n$ we get
$$\log n!=\sum_{k=1}^n\log k=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{d\mid k}\Lambda(d)=\sum_{d=1}^\infty\sum_{\substack{d\mid k\\k\leq n}}\Lambda(d)\\=\sum_{d=1}^\infty\sum_{l\leq n/d}\Lambda(d)=\sum_{l=1}^\infty\sum_{d\leq n/l}\Lambda(d)=\sum_{l=1}^\infty\psi(d).$$
Explanation of the steps: third and fifth equalities follow by exchanging the two summations, the fourth one follows by writing $k=dl$ and summing over $l$ in place of $k$.

Comment: Ah - it was the idea of going by ideals that didn't hit me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s a well-known identity. Think about how many factors of a prime $p$ are in $n!.$ There will be one for each multiple of $p$ less than it equal to $n$ where we count the multiple $n$ times if it’s a multiple of $p^n.$ Now for a given prime $p,$ $\psi(n)$ will contribute a factor for each prime $p$ less than or equal to $n$ with the proper muliplicity (since it also contributes a factor for all the prime powers).  Then $\psi(n/2)$ will contribute a factor for each multiples of $p$ of the form $2p^n,$ again counted with the correct multiplicity. And so on for $3p^n,$ $4p^n,$ etc. So we can see each prime $p$ is given the exact right number of factors so that the whole thing multiplies to $n!.$